# On my newly built PC, ubuntu freezes occasionally; but once a movie is playing, it works fine

Tags: 14.04, video, google-chrome, netflix

My cousin helped me by putting together a computer from his leftover parts. It has a M2N-MX SE motherboard and an AMD Athlon AM2 processor. So right from the start, I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3. On my other computers I just installed it alongside the Windows 7, and I haven't had major problems. I'm still new to Linux, but I like the community support. I use it mostly for internet, and the desktop version is easy to use.

Anyway, with this new computer, it will start up and then it goes black for a split second -- a few seconds after logging on. It might do this a couple times. But the real problem is when I get these diagonal lines and then it just freezes up. This will usually happen as I launch a web browser.

I have this computer mostly so that I can watch Netflix. I got it hooked up to the TV. I'm using Google Chrome to get it to work. So if I'm lucky enough to get a movie started, it will work just fine. It didn't freeze up once yet while watching a movie. I don't know what to do.

edit

Just tried the memtest from the GRUB. No errors.

edit

I just tried running it from the disc, same problem. Screen flickers at and a little after start up. And eventually come the blurry diagonal lines, the screen freezes, and computer doesn't respond.

I was messing around with the BIOS settings, for a while it seemed to work when I lowered the multiplier and voltage. But eventually it froze up again.

edit

fingers still crossed ... but it seems to be working now. Still flickers when launching things though sometimes. But here's what I did.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04. I messed with the BIOS and enabled the cool'n'quiet. I installed an Nvidia driver.

Keep in mind this is a custom built PC made from scraps. With my other computers, I had no problems.

Comment: Have you ran a RAM test.

Comment: I just did the memtest and it said no errors